# custome domain mapping to project running on azure with different port

Tags: azure, cname, domain-mapping

There are 6 projects running on single instance with different port.
which are 
http://stanthony.cloudapp.net
.
.
http://stanthony.cloudapp.net:86

Now I want to run each urls with different Domain, I did `CNAME` mapping with a domain but still same problem that all the ports are running with this single domain
www.kpmaurya.org
.
.
www.kpmaurya.org:86

I want to run all these urls with different domain
please let me know hoe can it be possible.

Answer (score 1):

In an Azure Web Role's service definition file you have a section for adding sites. Within this site you can add bindings section for each of you 6 sites with host header set to each of your custom domain.

Please refer this link for more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Comment: thanks alot to reply me ...
i have resolved the domain mapping .
this is too simple to set domain just go to the 
1) IIS manager
2) select the site name 
3) click on binding 
4) set the port 80 and enter the HostName(Domain name).
and now finished .
there is no any need to set hostheader at the time of deployment of the project.

Note: if you are running more than one site in single webrole , make sure the port address of all the site must be 80 and set different HostName (domain).


I think this may be helpful to newer one .

Comment: Are you using a web role or a vm role. Please be advised that all your custom settings will be lost in case your vm is reimaged which is not uncommon in cloud.